# Bootstrap: vertically align paragraph text and buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have text in a paragraph with a button `a` element:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Take exam</a> 
  <span class="text-muted">Available after reading course material</span>
</p>
```

However, this renders with the two not vertically aligned.

[image]

**What is the best way to align the text baseline here?**

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/0j20stbh/

Comment: This looks better than your picture imo? http://www.bootply.com/gtl3JhtLi0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the same styling as the `.btn` would probably be a good approach.  **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0j20stbh/3/)**  with disabled `.btn`

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Take exam</a> 
    <span class="text-muted btn" disabled="true">Text</span>
</p>
```

---

Or make a class of `.btn-align` with the same attributes. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0j20stbh/2/)

**CSS**

```
.btn-align {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Take exam</a> 
  <span class="text-muted btn-align">Available after reading course material</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 4, you can do this using utilities to set `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` in case you don't want to create a special CSS class for it.

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Take exam</a> 
    <span class="text-muted d-inline-block align-middle">Available after reading course material</span>
</p>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/obpwz7yc/1/)